# C Program runs in repl it compiler but not on gcc (seg fault) Cant find it

Tags: c

Apologies for the horrible indentation. For whatever reason it wont paste with it.
As in the title Im getting a segmentation error pointing to both main and ReadData funtion. However it doesnt say in which line. Ive tried multiple changes and it end sup in the same.

edit: gdb gives me:at vfscanf.c:1898 1898    vfscanf.c: No such file or directory.

As input Im using in.txt with:

```
-1 1 5 14
3 1
-6 -2
-4 2
4 -4
2 4
-1 3
2 2
0 -2
-4 -2
-6 6
4 4
-2 4
2 -2
-4 6
```

C CODE:

```
   #include<stdio.h>

   #include<stdlib.h>

   #include<math.h>

   /* point structure to store x & y co-ordinates */
   typedef struct {
     int x, y;
   }
   point;

   /* Prototype declarations*/
   point * ReadData(point * center, int * radius, int * nPoints);
   point * FilterData(point * data, point center, int radius, int * nPoints);
   void Merge(point * data, int p, int q, int r);
   void MergeSort(point * data, int p, int r);
   void BinarySearch(point * data, int nPoints, point p);
   void SearchPhase(point * data, int nPoints);

   int main() {
     point * data, * filter;
     point center;
     FILE * fp = fopen("out.txt", "w"); // output file out.txt
     int radius, nPoints, i;
     data = ReadData( & center, & radius, & nPoints); //call of ReadData()

     filter = FilterData(data, center, radius, & nPoints); // call of FilterData()

     MergeSort(filter, 0, nPoints - 1); // call of MersgeSort()
     for (i = 0; i < nPoints; i++)
       fprintf(fp, "%d\t%d\n", filter[i].x, filter[i].y); // writing to output file
     fclose(fp);
     printf("Filtered and sorted data written to out.txt");

     SearchPhase(filter, nPoints); // call of SearchPhase()
     return 0;
   }
   point * ReadData(point * center, int * radius, int * nPoints) {
     FILE * fp = fopen("in.txt", "r"); // input file in.txt
     point * ptr;
     int i, n;

     /* reading of center radius and no. of poins from file*/
     fscanf(fp, "%d%d%d%d", & center - > x, & center - > y, radius, nPoints);
     n = * nPoints;
     ptr = (point * ) malloc(sizeof(point) * n); // dynamic memory allocation
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
       fscanf(fp, "%d%d", & ptr[i].x, & ptr[i].y); // reading of x and y from file
     fclose(fp);
     return ptr;
   }

   point * FilterData(point * data, point center, int radius, int * nPoints) {
     point * filter;
     int n = * nPoints, i, j, pos, x, y;
     double dist;
     int * a = (int * ) calloc(sizeof(int), n); // dynamic memory allocation
     for (i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++) {
       x = data[i].x;
       y = data[i].y;
       dist = sqrt(pow(center.x - x, 2) + pow(center.y - y, 2)); // distance between center and point
       if (dist <= (double) radius) // if distance <= radius then point is within circle
       {
         a[j] = i;
         j++;
       }
     }
     * nPoints = j;
     filter = (point * ) malloc(sizeof(point) * j); // dynamic memory allocation
     for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
       pos = a[i];
       filter[i] = data[pos];
     }
     return filter;
   }

   /* Merge()*/
   void Merge(point * data, int p, int q, int r) {
     int n1 = q - p + 1;
     int n2 = r - q;
     point L[n1 + 1], R[n2 + 1];
     int i, j, k;

     for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
       L[i] = data[p + i];
     for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
       R[j] = data[q + 1 + j];

     point sentinel;
     sentinel.x = 999;
     sentinel.y = 999;
     L[n1] = sentinel;
     R[n2] = sentinel;
     i = 0, j = 0;
     for (k = p; k <= r; k++) {
       if (L[i].x < R[j].x || (L[i].x == R[j].x && L[i].y < R[j].y)) {
         data[k] = L[i];
         i++;
       } else {
         data[k] = R[j];
         j++;
       }
     }
   }

   /* MergeSort()*/
   void MergeSort(point * data, int p, int r) {
     int q, i;
     if (p < r) {
       q = (p + r) / 2;
       MergeSort(data, p, q);
       MergeSort(data, q + 1, r);
       Merge(data, p, q, r);
     }
   }

   /* BinarySearch()*/
   void BinarySearch(point * data, int nPoints, point p) {
     int l = 0, u = nPoints - 1, m, flag = 0;
     while (l <= u) {
       m = (l + u) / 2;
       if (data[m].x == p.x && data[m].y == p.y) {

         flag = 1;
         break;
       } else if (p.x < data[m].x || (p.x == data[m].x && p.y < data[m].y))
         u = m - 1;
       else
         l = m + 1;
     }

     if (flag)
       printf("\nOutput: Found at record %d", m + 1);
     else
       printf("\nOutput: Not Found");
   }

   /*SearchPhase()*/
   void SearchPhase(point * data, int nPoints) {
     point p;
     while (1) {
       printf("\nSearch input ( x y): ");
       scanf("%d%d", & p.x, & p.y);
       if (p.x == -999 || p.y == -999) {
         printf("\nOutput: Exit\n");
         break;
       }
       BinarySearch(data, nPoints, p);
     }
   }
```

Comment: "However it doesnt say in which line". What is "it"? Run your program in a debugger like gdb. The debugger will tell you precisely which line triggers the seg fault.

Comment: That code is unreadable. Not least because of the indentation but also because of all those one letter variables. It's virtually impossible to follow. Your best bet is to narrow down if not outright find the problem by using a debugger.

Comment: As a general tip for helping with debugging and finding errors: Don't test when the program is finished, test while working on it. Begin by writing something very small and simple, and test it. Then add another very small and simple thing, and test that. And so on. When there's a problem, you know which code to focus on (the last little small and simple piece of code you added), which makes it much simpler to find and fix problems.

Comment: Also build with verbose warnings enabled, the compiler is good at finding possible problems. And don't forget to add error checking for functions that can fail, like `fopen` and `malloc`. For example, what if the input file can't be opened (like what will happen if the directory where the program is running is not the same where the input file is located, which is unfortunately quite common). I'm ready to bet that this (`fopen` of the input file failing) is the problem you have.

Comment: Not repeatable as it is. The warnings of `clang -Weverything` are negligible (although should be done, nevertheless!) and `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all` is also ok with it (complains about the memory left over when you send it a SIGTERM which is expected but should be taken care of nevertheless!). Please add to your post a way (e.g.: used search-terms, how and with what you have build it, etc p.p.) to enable us to repeat your error.

Comment: I pretty much used both replt.it (which was fine) and gcc which gives me: :at vfscanf.c:1898 1898 vfscanf.c: No such file or directory. and the seg fault error

Comment: Don't cast the result from `malloc()` etc. It is unnecessary, and can mask the serious error of a missing prototype.

Comment: +1 for @Someprogrammerdude's comment about checking `fopen`.  When I ran your program without `in.txt` in the current directory, I get a segfault in `vfscanf` exactly as you report.  I would add that check right now.

Comment: If you use the `backtrace` command in gdb, you can see what line of your code is calling the offending function.  Then use `up` to get up the call chain into your code, and inspect the values of your variables and the arguments to `fscanf`.